# How to extend QClipboard?

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard-interaction

How can I extend `QClipboard` to allow selection of all text in all open windows.

Please provide code.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Visiting all sections of the [FAQ](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is not a waste of time: you will earn a badge :-) but also improve your proficiency.

Answer (score 1):

See [QClipboard](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QClipboard.html) it's very simple for just text

```
QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
QString getCLipboardText = clipboard->text();
QString newClipboardText("blah blah");
clipboard->setText(newClipboardText);
```

Comment: :Thanks for your reply. but i want to retrieve global selection of any text in any window

Comment: clipboard->text() will retrieve text from the clipboard - from whichever app it was copied from. There is only one system-wide clipboard